# Add Author Name, Short Title, Date, and Pages to Footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates, themes

I'm using the `default` theme. Not sure, if that theme uses the `infolines` outer theme or not. All I'm trying to achieve is add my name, the short title, the date (maybe with custom date format) and page number.

I thought there might be some simple way to achieve this with `\setbeamertemplate{footline}`, but all I could find was `[page number]` as option. How would I add the other attributes? Do I have to use `\makeatother` (I don't particularly understand how that works in first place)?

Answer (score 10):

You can define your own `footline`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{test}
\author{Einstein}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I change the date format to lets say `05 Jun 2014`?

Comment: Just set the date according to your preferences, e.g. `\date{05 Jun 2014}`